# Execute command on files found in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to concatenate linux commands - so I want to lint files using the `lint` command. But I only want to lint files with the .js extension.  I can find all these files by running this in the terminal:

```
find ./my-folder -name "*.js"
```

But how can I run the `lint` command on just these files in the terminal?

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to be about any programming problem. It is better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/). Try `man find` and you will find the answer there.

Answer (score 2):

```
find ./my-folder -name "*.js" -exec lint '{}' + \;
```

Use the exec flag of find to execute lint. {} will be a place holder for the found file paths and + will process as many files as once in one invocation.